# Why does a Beckmann Rearrangement not occur in the in nitrosation of cyclohexanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In my textbook Organic Chemistry, 2nd edition by Clayden, on pg. 464 it states the addition of $\ce{NO2-,HCl}$ to cyclohexanone to 2-nitrosocyclohexanone, which hydrolyses to 1,2-cyclohexadione. Why does the Beckmann rearrangement not occur in 2-nitrosocyclohexanone instead?

Comment: First, reaction conditions are important here. Second, do no assume that the nitroso is the same as the oxime.

Comment: Because the oxime hydrolysis is faster than the Beckmann rearrangement (after the nitroso has isomerised)